# Parsing a JSON file without JSON.parse()

Tags: ruby

This is my first time using Ruby. I'm writing an application that parses data and performs some calculations based on it, the source of which is a JSON file. I'm aware I can use JSON.parse() here but I'm trying to write my program so that it will work with other sources of data. Is there a clear cut way of doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When your source file is JSON then use `JSON.parse`. Do not implement a JSON parser on your own. If the source file is a CSV, then use the `CSV` class.

When your application should be able to read multiple different formats then just add one `Reader` class for each data type, like `JSONReader`, `CSVReader`, etc. And then decide depending on the file extension which reader to use to read the file.